# How to find the whether Jagged Array has next Element( HasNext) or not in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have to implement the below requirement but could not implement the solution for HasNext. Can someone please help me to implement this?

Array2d(int[][] input) - constructor that takes a 2d jagged array, see below for an example

- Next() - method that returns an integer

  When the Next() method is called the first time, it should return the first integer from the

  first non-empty inner array from the 2d jagged array or -1 if the 2d jagged array is empty.

  Then each subsequent call to Next(), return the next integer from the inner array or the first

  integer from the next inner array or -1 if the end of all inner arrays has been reached.
- HasNext() - method that returns a boolean.

  HasNext() should return true if there is another element in the 2d jagged array or false otherwise.

```
public interface ICustomIterator
{
    bool HasNext();
    int Next();
}
public class Array2D : ICustomIterator
{
    private int[][] _itemsList = null;
    int position = 0;
    int Currentcol = 0;
    bool hasNext = true;
    public Array2D(int[][] itemsList)
    {
        _itemsList = itemsList;
    }
    public bool HasNext()
    {
        if (position < _itemsList.Count())
        {
            if (_itemsList[position].Count() > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("HasNext:true");
            return true;
        }
        else if (position == _itemsList.Count() && hasNext == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HasNext:False");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("HasNext:False");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int Next()
    {
        if (_itemsList.Count() > position)
        {
            int[] itemContents = _itemsList[position];
            var len = itemContents.Length;
            if (len > Currentcol)
            {
                int test = itemContents[Currentcol];
                Console.WriteLine("Next returns :" + test);
                Currentcol++;
                if (Currentcol == len)
                {
                    position++;
                    Currentcol = 0;
                }
                return test;
            }
            else
            {
                position++;
                Currentcol = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hasNext = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Next returns:" + -1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
public class testMainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of rows");
        int[][] input = null;
        var test = Console.ReadLine();
        int x = Convert.ToInt32(test);
        input = new int[x][];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers separated by spaces?");
            string? col = Console.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(col))
            {
                input[i] = new int[] { };
            }
            else
            {
                input[i] = col.Split()?.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            }
        }
        ICustomIterator it = new Array2D(input);
        while (it.HasNext())
        {
            int item = it.Next();
            if (item > 0)
            {
                //  Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
<pre><code>
int[][] input = new int[][]

{

    new int[] { 1, 2 },

    new int[] {  },

    new int[] { 3 },

    new int[] { 4, 5 }

};

HasNext() returns: true
Next() returns:  1, HasNext() returns: true
Next() returns:  2, HasNext() returns: true
Next() returns:  3, HasNext() returns: true
Next() returns:  4, HasNext() returns: true
Next() returns:  5, HasNext() returns: false
Next() returns: -1, HasNext() returns: false

Output:

1
2
3
4
5
</pre></code>
```

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. Try something yourself. Hint: Each subarray has a Length property.

Comment: @PalleDue Bro, I haven't asked to write the program. I am trying to find a better solution for HasNext which is not available in the ienumerator. It was a very long post If I add my entire program here, so just avoided it. Thank you for the suggestion. Given the full problem statement for better understanding.

Comment: @PalleDue - Can you please help me to enhance the code with any patterns if possible?